# Require map: Getting module timeout when mapping extension

Tags: javascript, dictionary, requirejs, amd, shim

I got a Mediator-Sandbox library and a Router extension built on top of this library.

The library is built up like this:

```
(function(window) {

  var MedSan = {};

  window.MedSan = MedSan;

})(this);
```

The extension looks like this:

```
(function(_, Backbone, MedSan) {

  MedSan.Router = {};

})(_, Backbone, MedSan);
```

The requires config to load the extension looks like this:

```
require.config({

    baseUrl: "javascripts",

    shim: {
        "jquery": {
            exports: "$"
        },
        "underscore": {
            exports: "_"
        },
        "backbone": {
            deps: ['jquery', 'underscore'],
            exports: "Backbone"
        },
        "Distribution": {
            exports: "Distribution"
        },
        "Distribution.Router": {
            deps: ['underscore', 'backbone', 'Distribution'],
            exports: "Distribution"
        }
    },

    /*
    map: {
        "*": {
            "Distribution": "Distribution.Router"
        }         
    },
    */


    paths: {
        "jquery": "Vendors/jquery",
        "underscore": "Vendors/underscore",
        "backbone": "Vendors/backbone",

        "Distribution": "Distribution/Distribution",
        "Distribution.Router": "Distribution/Plugins/Router"
    }

});
```

I now can use my full library with:

```
require(['Distribution.Router'], function(Distribution) {});
```

when I uncomment the map configuration so I can use the full loaded module with router extension this way:

```
require(['Distribution'], function(Distribution) {});
```

than I am getting a module timeout.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you map `Distribution` to `Distribution.Router`, you're creating a circular dependency because `Distribution.Router` also depends on `Distribution`.

To fix this just add another line overriding the map for `Distribution` in `Distribution.Router` only:

```
map: {
    "*": {
        "Distribution": "Distribution.Router"
    },
    "Distribution.Router": {
        "Distribution": "Distribution"
    }
}
```